# UItableViewCell acting as a button

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I cannot get the right way to do the following stuff... (I'm sure I'm not that far but...)
I have a UITableView and within this table I want a particuliar cell to be displayed as a button.
At first I tried to add a button in the cell but I read that was not the right way to do it. Instead it seems better to customize the cell (and make it look like a button). The thing is, I do not really know what subview to change... 
What I need:
- no arrow beeing displayed at the right of the cell (I though UITableViewCellAccessoryNone would do the trick... but it did not...).
- the cell to be blue (same blue as the one used when it's clicked)

Below is the code I use:

```
NSString *section = (NSString *)[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSNumber *row = indexPath.row;
NSString *cellValue = (NSString *)[(NSArray *)[items objectForKey:section] objectAtIndex:row]; 
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

// Make Cell look like a button (used for disconnect option)
if([[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"connection"]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Disconnect";
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    for (UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
    cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Luc

Comment: What `UITableViewCellStyle` do you create this cell with? Is the table view a grouped table view?

Comment: the style is UITableViewCellStyleDefault. Yes this is a grouped table view. The cell I want to customize is the only one in it's group.

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete the code for cell Accessory view..
and to make it looks like a button, there are several possible solutions . you can make a background image for the cell like button . if you are facing a problem of accessory view that its not hiding , make an image like a button , and set the background image property of cell .

[Cell setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"Yourfilename.png"]];

something like this , if this doesn't work and try adding the image in cell subview ..

[Cell addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]]];

this may help !!!

Thanks
Yasir

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this without any image ? I mean, just by changing the cell color and play with the accessorize view ?